# How to type backslash and pipe? (Czech layout, USB keyboard)

Tags: macos, keyboard

I use an USB keyboard with my Macbook Pro - no choice here, some of the keys of internal keyboard are damaged. The Keyboard is from Genius, type LuxeMate i200. I use Czech QWERTY layout.

Everything pretty much works, although I can't seem to find a way how to type **backslash** `\` and **pipe** `|` characters.

Above the right Enter, I have a mysterious key with following characters:

- first row: `|` `)` `;`
- second row: `\` `ň` `¨` (and "circle in front of x" i can't even type)

I've tried the following:

- key: `¨`
- left SHIFT + key: `
- right SHIFT + key: `
- left ALT + key: `¨`
- right ALT + key: `¨`
- left SHIFT + key: `"`
- right SHIFT + key: `"`
- FN + key: `¨`

I would really like to avoid switching between keyboards OR copying the characters from Google, as I use them a lot. Can someone help me please?

EDIT: Here is a photo of the keyboard, if that helps.

[image: Screenshot of my keyboard]

EDIT 2: Thanks @krnk, the keyboard viewer helped with the backslash character! I still have a problem with the pipe character though.

What the viewer shows is not consistent with the keyboard (there is no key between left shift and Z key, for example, which would solve my problem with the pipe). Is that maybe another symptom of misconfiguration?

[image]

Is there anything else I could try besides "changing keyboard type" (which I already did)?

Comment: @krnk: Thanks a lot for your suggestion, it helped! I have updated my question.

Comment: That is what I meant by "changing keyboard type", so yes, I did. The assistant asked me for key right of L Shift (Z) and left of R Shift (- and _). The keyboard viewer still shows incorrect layout (key right of as backslash).

Answer (score 1):

I just bought a Genius keyboard in the Czech Republic and have the same problem, however I've found the following works for me:

- Right <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Right <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>|</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Just been fiddling with my Czech Microsoft Sculpt ergonomic and it turns out that the <kbd>\</kbd>  & <kbd>|</kbd> key is mapped to the <kbd>;</kbd> under the <kbd>Esc</kbd> to the left of <kbd>1</kbd> key. So by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>, I get the <kbd>|</kbd>.

Answer (score -1):

To get the backslash character (\) using the Czech keyboard layout press <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>.

Comment: Mac doesn't have an AltGr key.

Comment: Worked for me for Slovak keyboard. I did have a alt gr key